# Why taking a bomb with you to the airplane won't improve your chances of survival

Tags: logic

There was an old woman, who had to take a flight for the first time and she was terrified of the prospect that someone had a bomb there, so she called the company and asked how likely it was that there was a bomb. Extremely small, the company answered. The woman then asked, how likely it was that there are two bombs. Far far more unlikely than that there was only one bomb, they answered. So the woman went on the flight with a bomb.

Prove logically that this reasoning is not valid.

Comment: Perhaps the problem could be reworded, why not the CEO of a major corporation?

Comment: Please note that most people here find rude to write a question that looks like it consists only of a verbatim quote from an exercise sheet with no thought of the asker's own to go with it, as shown by the sarcasm in @André's comment. Please consider telling us in what context you encountered the problem and what did you do in order to solve it.

Comment: @A.P.: Actually, I was objecting to "old" and "woman."

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ha, sorry. Now that I look more closely I see that you wrote "reworded" and not "rewarded"... my fault (I still think that the current wording is impolite at best, though).

Comment: @A.P. Heh, well, this was actually a joke I read somewhere many years ago and I remember wondering why it isn't valid reasoning and it popped to my head today. I was thinking the whole issue maybe from some sort of game theoretic point of view. Like how the knowledge the woman has and the woman acting on it cannot advance her chances of "winning". Or purely logical, like "I take a bomb with me implies other person won't take a bomb."

Comment: I see. Then it would probably have been better to say so in the statement of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The events are (presumably) [independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29):  $$\mathrm{Pr}[\text{someone else having a bomb}]=\mathrm{Pr}[\text{someone else having a bomb}|\text{old woman has a bomb}].$$

The fact that the old woman has a bomb makes no difference to the probability of someone else having a bomb (unless, say, she happens to be with a terrorist organisation and tends to fly with other terrorists).

Comment: Probabilities are degrees of belief, and the woman has evidence of one bomb, so her posterior belief of the parameter is updated and hence smaller.

Comment: Surely in this situation that degree of belief is backed by something tangible though - the likelihood of the plane being blown up by somebody on board with a bomb. The question is about chance of survival, not perceived chance of survival. So, since she won't blow her bomb up, the chance of survival isn't changed by her bomb would be my approach.

Comment: It's a good approach.

Comment: Events are not always independent. I watch lots of soccer on television. If I go to the kitchen (where I can't see the television), a goal is scored. Counterintuitive, I know.

Comment: I know this is old but it seems to me to be begging the question. OP provided a reasoning that seems to lead to the conclusion that these events are not independent, and you attempt to prove his reasoning wrong by simply negating his conclusion.